# Cannot compile classes into their own binaries for later linking

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, makefile

I am trying to compile multiple classes into their own binaries to use later during linking.  I have the following files:

Gradebook.h

```
#ifndef GRADEBOOK_H
#define GRADEBOOK_H

class Gradebook {
  public:
    Gradebook(double);
    Gradebook();
    void setGrade(double);
    double getGrade();

  private:
    double currentGrade;
};

#endif
```

Gradebook.cpp

```
#include "Gradebook.h"
Gradebook::setGrade(double grade){
    currentGrade = grade;
}

Gradebook::getGrade(){
    return currentGrade;
}

Gradebook::Gradebook(double grade){
    currentGrade = grade;
}

Gradebook::Gradebook(){}
```

When I attempt to compile:

```
$ g++ -c Gradebook.cpp
```

I get the following errors:

```
Gradebook.cpp:2:12: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
Gradebook::setGrade(double grade){
~~~~~~~~~  ^
Gradebook.cpp:3:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'currentGrade'
  currentGrade = grade;
  ^
Gradebook.cpp:6:12: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
Gradebook::getGrade(){
~~~~~~~~~  ^
Gradebook.cpp:7:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'currentGrade'
  return currentGrade;
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks

UPDATE:

Now I have it compiling, as I specified the return types within the cpp file  However, when I try to link everything together, I get more errors.  I am using the following makefile:

```
all : main.o Gradebook.o
        g++ main.o Gradebook.o -o build

main.o: main.cpp
        g++ -c main.cpp

Gradebook.o: Gradebook.cpp
        g++ -c Gradebook.h

clean:
        rm -rf *.o build

run:
        ./build
```

And I get the following errors when I run make:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file Gradebook.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x43 0x50 0x43 0x48 0x01 0x0C 0x00 0x00 0x27 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x0B 0x02 0x68 0x42 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): Gradebook.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Gradebook::getGrade()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "Gradebook::setGrade(double)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "Gradebook::Gradebook(double)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "Gradebook::Gradebook()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Note you should use `g++` instead of `gcc` if you're compiling C++ code.

Comment: You're missing a return type for the member function implementation.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I am using g++

Comment: Useful to put the arguments name in the header file as well. People tend to use the header file as reference

Comment: Ya this is just a sample program.  I am getting re-acquainted with C/C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify the return type of your methods.

```
void Gradebook::setGrade(double grade){
    currentGrade = grade;
}

double Gradebook::getGrade(){
    return currentGrade;
}
```

The make rule for GradeBook.o is wrong, you are compiling the .h file. Try this:

```
Gradebook.o: Gradebook.cpp
        g++ -c Gradebook.cpp
```

Comment: Thats strange.  I can compile it together with a main and no errors get thrown and it works

Comment: It's posted above, including makefile.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with one of the build recipes in your makefile:

```
Gradebook.o : Gradebook.cpp
    g++ -c Gradebook.h
```

When building a translation unit you want to compile the `.cpp` file, not the header file as a stand-alone. The current setup will not include the method implementation for your class since `gradebook.cpp` is never compiled.

Try this instead:

```
Gradebook.o : Gradebook.cpp
    g++ -c $^ -o $@
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I would give you the credit, but the original question was answered above.

Comment: While I have you, do you know of any unit testing suites for C/C++?  Something easy that I can cli within the make file?

Comment: There's quite a few around for c++. I personally like google test(gtest for short). Just google for it ;)